# How can I access item in parent repeat template while in filter

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer

```
<iron-pages>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fruit_categories}}" as="category">
        <div>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{all_fruits}}" as="fruit"
                      filter="isThisFruitInTheRightCategory">
                <!-- Some more stuff -->
                <span>{{fruit.weight}}</span>
                <span>{{fruit.age}}</span>
                <!-- ... -->
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</iron-pages>

isThisFruitInTheRightCategory: function(fruit){
    return fruit.category === /* Q: How do I get the current category? */
}
```

Suppose I have an array containing all the category names, and another array containing all the fruits I have in a basket with their own properties. I want to display them in their respective page in right category.

I tried to use a filter to filter out fruits that do not belong to the current category, however I can't seem to figure out a way to access the parent (`{{category}}`).

What would a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to bind the `filter` property to a filter generator, like so:

`filter="{{filterForCategory(category)}}"`

and then

```
        filterForCategory: function(category) {
          return function(fruit) {
            return fruit.category === category;
          }
        }
```

Full example here:

```
<dom-module id="x-example">
  <template>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fruit_categories}}" as="category">
      <h2>{{category}}</h2>
      <div>

         <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{all_fruits}}" as="fruit" filter="{{filterForCategory(category)}}">
          <span>{{fruit.name}}</span><br>
        </template>

      </div>
    </template>

  </template>
  <script>

      Polymer({
        is: "x-example",
        properties: {
          fruit_categories: {
            value: ['apples', 'oranges']
          },
          all_fruits: {
            value: [
              {name: 'fuji', category: 'apples'},
              {name: 'granny smith', category: 'apples'},
              {name: 'navel', category: 'oranges'}
            ]
          }
        },
        filterForCategory: function(category) {
          return function(fruit) {
            return fruit.category === category;
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: One more question: If one of the category is empty, I would like to show a special text to indicate there's nothing. I was thinking about using `dom-if`, but there isn't a way to get the length. What should I do?

Comment: It's not ideal, but you can do `dom-if if="{{isEmpty(all_fruits, category)}}` and then `isEmpty: function(fruits, category) { return fruits.filter(this.filterForCategory(category)).length == 0; }`

Comment: Thanks, that works, but if the arrays is changed, Polymer seems to not able to pick that up and reevaluate the expression unless I missed something.

Comment: I'm guessing about what you mean by "arrays is changed", but you can try: `dom-if if="{{isEmpty(all_fruits, category, all_fruits.*)}} and then isEmpty: function(fruits, category) { return fruits.filter(this.filterForCategory(category)).length == 0; }`